# How to solve this Complex inequality system

Tags: inequality

$1 \leq z \overline {z} \leq 4$ and $|\Im(z)|<\Re (z)$

How can I solve this system of inequalities? ($\Im$ is the imaginary part and $\Re$ is the real part of a complex number).

I have tried so far: $z=x+yi$ and then I get $1 \leq x^2+y^2 \leq 4$ and $ |y|<x$. How can I solve this?

Comment: Draw a picture.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**

$$1\leq z\bar z\leq 4\iff  1\leq |z|^2\leq 4\iff 1\leq |z|\leq 2$$

$$|\Im(z)|<\Re(z)\iff \arg(z)\in]-\frac{\pi}{4},\frac{\pi}{4}[$$